# How can I set the order in which controls get created?

Tags: c#, asp.net

It seems that the order in which controls are declared in the .aspx does not guarantee the order in which they get rendered/loaded/created.

Is it possible to set the order in which controls are 'rendered' ? Some of my control events have side effects, that is why... (In my case I have two `DetailsView` controls, and I need to be sure the `ItemCreated` of one always gets called before the other one's).

Maybe there is just a way to 'wait' in an event until another one is triggered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually only a matter of calling `DataBind` separately on the controls, in the desired sequence, instead of defaulting to `Page.DataBind`.